# Не работает wrap_content в ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

У меня есть ImageView c шириной *match_parent*, и с высотой *wrap_content*. 
Когда я задаю изображение с размером 1080x500, ImageView по ширине занимает весь экран но по высоте почему то занимает лишний пространство. Я знаю про adjustviewbounds, но мне интересно почему imageView занимает дополнительную пространству. У меня телефон Pixel(1080x1920).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что этот виджет в дефолтных параметрах квадратный, если изображение не квадратное, то оно занимает не все пространство виджета, но и виджет своего не уступит :)